# Root View Controller not changing on BOOL

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to change the Root View controller if the application has been opened once. Here is what im doing. The boolean is fully functional and i know because it prints 'Welcome Back'. Here is what im trying to do.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // App Already launched
        RootMenuController *viewController = [[RootMenuController alloc] init];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = viewController;
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // This is the first launch ever

    }

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The only problem I see is in the else statment you're not loading a view controller.

Comment: who would i load the view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are not setting/updating application window properly. I have created an sample project which might help. https://github.com/deepthit/UpdateRootViewController.git

Comment: Im getting This error: property's synthesized getter follows Cocoa naming convention for returning 'owned' objects
on the project that you have given me

Comment: Hi prnk28, committed changes to fix that error. Can you try now?

Comment: I have an issue with the code You are using XIB's but however i am using storyboards and when I try to instiniate the view controller like this it always gives me an error.

Comment: self.updatedRootViewController = [[RootMenuController alloc] init];